# JavaScript recursion, reversing array

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't understand why the following code snippet leads to error. Any ideas?

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array, low, high) {
  if (low == undefined) {
    low = 0;
  }
  if (high == undefined) {
    high = array.length - 1;
  }

  if (low >= high) {
    return;
  }

  var temp = array[low];
  array[low] = array[high];
  array[high] = temp;

  return reverseArrayInPlace(array, low++, high--);
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: That means your base case, `if (low >= high)` isn't being hit. You always fall through to the recursive case, which the JS engine eventually blocks because otherwise it would go on forever. Maybe that will help you debug the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, true, base case is not hit, questions is why exactly, low is incremented with each call, and high is decremented, eventually there has to point for condition of low >= high to be true

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger to track down problems like this. Or at least put in some `console.log` calls to track what values are being passed in.

Comment: @TedHopp Could not run code at all, so could not use debugger. Thank you for advise.

Comment: @TedHopp I suspect that he could spend hours in the debugger and he'd never have figured out why the recursive call wasn't passing in the expected values.

Comment: Either you understand how `low++` works or you don't, and he didn't.

Comment: If the code did not run at all, it wouldn't be crashing with that error. The idea would be to step through the program to examine what values are being passed around.

Comment: @TedHopp He probably also doesn't know how to set breakpoints in the debugger, so as soon as he starts it it crashes.

Comment: @Barmar - Perhaps not. But at least OP could have discovered that the same values were being passed in at each recursive call.

Comment: I do understand difference between post- and pre-increment, just did not pay attention in this case, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're using post-increment and post-decrement. It increments/decrements the variable, but returns the old value, so you're passing the old value in the recursion. As a result, the recursive call is identical to the original call, and you recurse infinitely.

Pre-increment/decrement -- `++low` and `--high` -- would work correctly. But you don't need to update the variables at all, since you never use them again. Just do normal addition/subtraction.

There's also no point in using `return reverseArrayInPlace()` when you make the recursive call, because the base case doesn't return anything. Just make the recursive call without putting it in a `return` statement.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array, low, high) {
  if (low == undefined) {
    low = 0;
  }
  if (high == undefined) {
    high = array.length - 1;
  }

  if (low >= high) {
    return;
  }

  var temp = array[low];
  array[low] = array[high];
  array[high] = temp;

  reverseArrayInPlace(array, low + 1, high - 1);
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: OP also doesn't need a `return` with the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks, got it, missed the case.

Comment: There's also no point in using return when you make the recursive call, because the base case doesn't return anything. 
Could you please clarify - I am using return in base case just to quit function.

Comment: You use `return` but not `return someExpression`, so it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I don't mean to return anything, I use return to quit from recursive calls;

Comment: I understand that. So what's the point of doing `return reverseArrayInplace(...)`? That returns the value that the recursive call returns, but the recursive call doesn't return anything. Just make the recursive call and then the function ends.

Comment: Point of doing return reverseArrayInplace(...) is to make next recursive call to swap next 2 array values. Once I reach the middle there is no need to make next recursive call, as values are reversed by now, so I quit (by 'return')

Comment: You can make the recursive call without using `return`. Just write `reveseArrayInPlace(...)` like in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141733/discussion-between-fg78nc-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

because you have to use ++low and --high in the recursive call.
in your version the values are first passed and then modified.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array, low, high) {
  if (low == undefined) {
    low = 0;
  }
  if (high == undefined) {
    high = array.length - 1;
  }

  if (low >= high) {
    return;
  }

  var temp = array[low];
  array[low] = array[high];
  array[high] = temp;

  return reverseArrayInPlace(array, ++low, --high);
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: Using pre-increment and pre-decrement is a waste; those variables are dead after the recursive call. Just recurse with `low + 1` and `high - 1`.